# Is there a way to get the parent execution given an execution id in Camunda?

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the parent execution of an execution in camunda. What I'm trying to achieve is basically the following:

[image: Simple parallel gateway process]

This is a simple process involving a parallel gateway. Each of the flows is composed of a service task (external) and a user task.

In each "Pre: Task X" service task, I want to set some variables that I will use afterward in their respective user tasks. I want each execution flow of the parallel gateway to have their own variables and non-accessible from the other flows. How can I achieve this?

I was doing some tests and I found the following:

When the process is instantiated, I get instantly 5 execution instances.
What I understand is that one belongs to the process, the next two belong to each flow of the parallel gateway, and the last two belong to each of the service tasks.

If I call "complete" for one of the service tasks on the REST API with localVariables, they will instantly disappear and no further be available because they will be tied to the execution associated to the external task, which is terminated after the task completion.

Is there a way in which I can get the parent execution of the task, which in this case would be the parallel execution flow. So I can set localVariables at this level?

Thanks in advance for the valuable help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all 5 executions doesn't mean they are active. In your case there should only be 2 executions active when you start a new instance for the process. You can set your variables in respective executions as return value of the respective service tasks.

You can set variables for process instance but do respect you have 2 executions and 1 process instance. You can not set same variable for multiple executions.